# In the given code, there is no definition of getArea. But there are no errors? How?

Tags: java

In the given code, the programmer hasn't defined the methods like `getArea` and nowhere is mentioned which parameter in brackets is "width" and which is "height".
I am new to Java. Please help me understand the code.

Thats the code taken from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objects.html

```
public class CreateObjectDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Declare and create a point object and two rectangle objects.
        Point originOne = new Point(23, 94);
        Rectangle rectOne = new Rectangle(originOne, 100, 200);
        Rectangle rectTwo = new Rectangle(50, 100);

        // display rectOne's width, height, and area
        System.out.println("Width of rectOne: " + rectOne.width);
        System.out.println("Height of rectOne: " + rectOne.height);
        System.out.println("Area of rectOne: " + rectOne.getArea());

        // set rectTwo's position
        rectTwo.origin = originOne;

        // display rectTwo's position
        System.out.println("X Position of rectTwo: " + rectTwo.origin.x);
        System.out.println("Y Position of rectTwo: " + rectTwo.origin.y);

        // move rectTwo and display its new position
        rectTwo.move(40, 72);
        System.out.println("X Position of rectTwo: " + rectTwo.origin.x);
        System.out.println("Y Position of rectTwo: " + rectTwo.origin.y);
    }
}
```

This program creates, manipulates, and displays information about various objects. Here's the output:

> Width of rectOne: 100
>   Height of rectOne: 200
>   Area of rectOne: 20000
>   X Position of rectTwo: 23
>   Y Position of rectTwo: 94
>   X Position of rectTwo: 40
>   Y Position of rectTwo: 72

Comment: You've only included the main method of what looks like a driver class, where is the Rectangle class?

Comment: ...because it's a method of the `Rectangle` object, which you haven't shown us the definition of?

Comment: I have included the code from the website .

Comment: From the [page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objects.html) you found this on:  [Point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/examples/Point.java) and [Rectangle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/examples/Rectangle.java) are links, to the classes used.  It specifically states: "You will need all three source files to compile this program."  Please read more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the other classes it links to on the website.

> You will need all three source files to compile this program.

[CreateObjectDemo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/examples/CreateObjectDemo.java)

[Rectangle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/examples/Rectangle.java)

[Point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/examples/Point.java)

The `getArea` method is in the `Rectangle` class

Comment: thanks ! yes thats makes sense now that we have to define the getArea  method in Rectangle class. :)

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned Rectangle or Point classes are not java.awt.Rectangle and java.awt.Point classes. They are the [Point](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/examples/Point.java) and [Rectangle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/examples/Rectangle.java) classes which their links are given before the code.

Answer (score -1):

```
`Rectangle` and `Point` are java built-in classes.
```

<del>Those methods are already defined. 

    Check the documentation: 
    http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html
    http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html</del>

EDIT: From the link you have just shown, it says there it's using those classes:

```
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/examples/Point.java
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/examples/Rectangle.java
```

Comment: It's not using those classes, but it is using other classes.

Comment: There isn't any method getArea provided by Java built-in class.

Comment: How do we know that we don't have to define method as its already available? There are many classes defined in a package. Do we have look everytime in package?

Comment: If it's already defined somewhere, you have to include it in your file. For instance, if you need to use an ArrayList, you have to 'import java.util.ArrayList;' in the beggining of your file.

Comment: Point and Rectangle Classes provided by Java don't have getArea() method.

Comment: Yes, I realized that after posting, unfortunately. @RanchoInside posted the source website later, where the needed classes are shown.

Comment: Yes thats true @hugo Sousa ! NExt time I will post the all the links as well.